# Find all duplicate cells, Identify if value exist that matches the duplicate, Fill in next column of the duplicate row cell has value of 0

Tags: excel

This is a little complex, but if anyone can help. I would be greatful.

[image]

What I want to do is:

1. Find duplicate values in column A (sku)
2. If a value exist in column D for that duplicate cell
3. Fill column E with the value in D IF column C = 0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use unique() to make a unique list, or make a copy and use the button « remove duplicates » in the data tab. Then index() with match().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this by entering the following formula into E2 with `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER` (prior to Excel 365) and then copying it down:

`=IFERROR(IF(C2=0,INDEX($D$2:$D$20,MATCH(1,(A2=$A$2:$A$20)*(""<>$D$2:$D$20),0)),""),"")`

Adjust `$A$20` and `$D$20` to the full length of your ranges.

The important part is `(A2=$A$2:$A$20)*(""<>$D$2:$D$20)`. This produces an array with `1` for each row where `$A$2:$A$20` equals `A2` and `$D$2:$D$20` is not empty, and `0` for all others. The first (and here: only) match will result in `5`, which we'll use within `INDEX` to get the value (to be returned only when `C2=0`). The `IFERROR` rectifies any `#N/A errors`.

Hope this helps.